# Javascript drag and drop exhibiting strange behavior

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to create a drag and drop form builder, and I'm encountering some weird issues with my basic drag event handlers.

Specifically, the draggable elements are acting like they have event listeners from the drop target, but when I inspect the elements, they only have the event listeners from the drag elements.

Is this an issue of inheritance? Is there something I can do to prevent draggable items from acting like the drop target?

Thanks!

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test Page</title>
        <style>
            .drag 
            {
                border: solid;
                margin: auto;
                width: 80px;
            }
            .drop
            {
                border: solid;
                margin: auto;
                min-height: 100px;
                width: 100px;
            }
            .over 
            {
                border: 2px dashed #000;
            }
            .palette
            {
                position: absolute;
                top: 10px;
                left: 10px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="test.js"></script>

        <div id="palette" class="palette">
            <div id="1" draggable="true" class="drag">Test 1</div>
            <div id="2" draggable="true" class="drag">Test 2</div>
            <div id="3" draggable="true" class="drag">Test 3</div>
            <div id="4" draggable="true" class="drag">Test 4</div>
            <div id="5" draggable="true" class="drag">Test 5</div>
        </div>
        <div id="target" class="drop">


        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
window.onload = initall;    

function initall() 
{   
    var allDivs = document.getElementsByTagName('DIV');
    for (var i = 0; i < allDivs.length; i++) 
    {
        if(allDivs[i].className == "drag") 
        {
            allDivs[i].addEventListener('dragstart', handleDragStart);
            allDivs[i].addEventListener('dragend', handleDragEnd);

        }

        if(allDivs[i].className == "drop") 
        {
            allDivs[i].addEventListener('dragenter', handleDragEnter,true);
            allDivs[i].addEventListener('dragover', handleDragOver,true);
            allDivs[i].addEventListener('dragleave', handleDragLeave,true);
            allDivs[i].addEventListener('drop', handleDrop,true);


        }
    }
}


/*
 * Functions for element being dragged
 */

function handleDragEnd(ev)
{
    ev.target.style.opacity = '1';
}
function handleDragStart(ev) 
{
    ev.target.style.opacity = '0.4';
    ev.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
} 

/*
 * Functions for drop target
 */

function handleDragEnter(ev) 
{

    ev.target.classList.add('over');

}
function handleDragLeave(ev) 
{
    ev.target.classList.remove('over');
}

function handleDragOver(ev) 
{
    if (ev.preventDefault) {
        ev.preventDefault();
    }
    ev.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "move";

}
function handleDrop(ev) 
{
    if (ev.preventDefault) {
        ev.preventDefault();
    }

    if(ev.target.className.indexOf("drop") > -1)
    {
        var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
        ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
        ev.target.classList.remove('over');
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try false instead of true as third arguments in the addeventlisteners attached to the drop divs.

Comment: I actually added the true to try and resolve this (false being the default) but went ahead and explicitly said false and gave it a try. The behavior is exactly the same.

Comment: I tried your code and  the draggable divs don't behave like elements having drop listeners. Could you describe their behaviour more precisely ?

Comment: When a dragenter event is caught, the "over" class is applied to the target... in this case, that means when I drag test1 to the target, it works as expected, but if I drag one of the other elements over the test 1, the class is applied to that element. It is true, that it is not becoming a drop target, and that is part of my confusion. I believe that it's only because I'm checking to see if the target has a drop class before actually performing the drop.

Comment: I don't see this behaviour with my versions of FF and chromium. The borders stay solid not dashed.

Comment: Huh. That's really strange. I see the behavior in Chrome, FF, and IE.

Chrome Version 51.0.2704.103 m
FF Version 47.0.1
IE 11.0.9600.17843

I may have to try this on someone else's computer and see if I can reproduce